# How to mask ":" in a first row in AutoHotKey Hotstring?

Tags: windows, autohotkey

How to mask ":" in a first row in AutoHotKey Hotstring? I want to type "colors:" and get "red, violet, blue".

```
::colors':::
Send, 
(
red, violet, blue
)
return
```

Answer (score 1):

`:` is an [ending character](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#EndChars) by default. You only have to define

```
::colors':: ; or/and  
::colors::
Send, 
(
red, violet, blue
)
return
```

and press `:` after typing `colors'` or `colors`.

Comment: That answers my question only partly. I realized that when I type "colors:", I get the desired result somehow. But I also get two unnecessary shortcuts I lean to avoid: "colors" and "colors'".

Comment: Then use another character instead of `:`, e.g. `/` or `<`.

Comment: Yes, it works. Well, close enough, I guess. :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Hotstring()` function](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Hotstring.htm) if you want the trigger string to end with a colon:

```
Hotstring("::colors:", "red, violet, blue")
```

Then, when you type "colors:" + <kbd>Space</kbd>, you get the text "red, violet, blue " – notice the trailing space. If you don't want the trailing space, you can for example change the trigger string to `:O:colors:`. Consult the [Hotstrings documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm) for more options.

---

If your AHK script also contains hotstrings that are defined with a double-colon label (e.g. `::foo::bar`), they must be defined *after* defining hotstrings using the `Hotstring()` function:

```
; WRONG - the second hotstring won't work
::shapes::triangle, circle, rectangle
Hotstring("::colors:", "red, violet, blue")
```

```
; CORRECT
Hotstring("::colors:", "red, violet, blue")
::shapes::triangle, circle, rectangle
```

This is because the first hotstring label (or the first `return`, `exit` or hotkey label) in the script ends the script's [auto-execute section](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto). So, the `Hotstring()` function never gets called if it's outside of the auto-execute section.